# Coverage decreases?

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab

Can anyone explain to me the meaning of the message and error i.e. **"converge decreased (-0.3%) to 14.067% when pulling a561b6d on NihalAgarwal:master into c60020b on opsdroid:master"** occurs while doing commit on oper source project?

Comment: Assuming "converge" is a typo for "coverage", this has nothing to do with the tags you've used: it's part of a coverage test, probably done by a CI system. Coverage testing is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project measures the test coverage, i.e. what percentage of the code gets actually run when running the tests. The message means you added code that isn't tested or removed some tests so a part of the codebase is no longer tested.

Comment: I had changes some few lines of code neither added new method or delete, only changed some line in a already defined method.

Comment: @AarravAgarwal: Without seeing the actual changes, we can only guess. Maybe your changes introduced a new `if` but the tests don't execute both the `then` and `else` parts?